# php-fpm process in D state ,cause nfs wait rpc_wait_bit_killable

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, wordpress, php-fpm, linux-networking

my wordpress site which is in clustered environment using NFS,nginx,php-fpm,mysql the infrastructure is  hosted on amazon ec2.Under high load/traffic the php5-fpm process goes in D state(uninterrutable sleep) and website crashes.
Upon checking with the command

```
echo w > /proc/sysrq-trigger; dmesg -c | less;
```

found the php-fpm is in blocked state
Kernel Stack trace

> [6615425.408345] SysRq : Show Blocked State [6615425.408362]   task
>   PC stack   pid father [6615425.408444] php5-fpm        D
>   0000000000000000     0 16616  12079 0x00000000 [6615425.408453] 
>   ffff880001793938 0000000000000246 ffff880001793fd8 0000000000014580
>   [6615425.408457]  ffff880001793fd8 0000000000014580 ffff88001cad1770
>   ffff88001cad1770 [6615425.408460]  ffff88006c88ba00 0000000000000082
>   ffffffffa0044190 ffff8800017939b0 [6615425.408463] Call Trace:
>   [6615425.408491]  [] ?
>   __rpc_wait_for_completion_task+0x30/0x30 [sunrpc] [6615425.408497]  [] schedule+0x29/0x70 [6615425.408506] 
>   [] rpc_wait_bit_killable+0x35/0x90 [sunrpc]
>   [6615425.408511]  [] __wait_on_bit+0x60/0x90
>   [6615425.408516]  [] ? __queue_work+0x135/0x330
>   [6615425.408524]  [] ?
>   __rpc_wait_for_completion_task+0x30/0x30 [sunrpc] [6615425.408528]  [] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x77/0x90
>   [6615425.408532]  [] ?
>   wake_atomic_t_function+0x40/0x40 [6615425.408540] 
>   [] __rpc_wait_for_completion_task+0x2d/0x30 [sunrpc]
>   [6615425.408553]  [] nfs4_run_open_task+0x11f/0x170
>   [nfsv4] [6615425.408563]  [] ?
>   nfs4_get_open_state+0x76/0x1b0 [nfsv4] [6615425.408571] 
>   [] nfs4_do_open+0x1d8/0x930 [nfsv4] [6615425.408581]
>   [] ? generic_lookup_cred+0x15/0x20 [sunrpc]
>   [6615425.408591]  [] ? rpcauth_lookupcred+0x77/0xc0
>   [sunrpc] [6615425.408603]  [] ?
>   nfs_do_access+0x69/0x250 [nfs] [6615425.408610]  []
>   nfs4_atomic_open+0xd4/0xe0 [nfsv4] [6615425.408619] 
>   [] nfs4_file_open+0xb9/0x1b0 [nfsv4]

Also i  found php5-fpm segfault with errror 4 in dmesg often.

The OS is ubuntu 12.04LTS on which nfs-kernel-server is running and on client side the OS is Ubuntu 13.04 which nfsv4.I have tried upgrading the instance size of NFS server and also increased the NFS server threads but not effect.

Could not find a suitable solution to this till now.

Comment: We had a similar issue. any clue on solution?